# How to make 2 panels appear one after the other on wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, panel

I created 2 panels in the main window with wxpython (coded with python 3.9).
After the first processing I ask that the results appear in the first panel and that this one is displayed.
Then the second treatment must start and display the result in the second panel.
My problem is that the 2 panels update when the last treatment is finished and not one after the other.
I tried to wait for a return value from the first method without success!
Here is my code :

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled
import wx.grid as grid
import time


class PanelChoice(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PanelChoice, self).__init__(parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('#BDBDBD')

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label='Select data')
        hbox.Add(self.label, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 12)

        list_choice = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
        self.choice = wx.ComboBox(self, choices=list_choice)
        self.choice.SetValue('1')
        hbox.Add(self.choice, 0,  wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 3)

        self.btn_go = wx.Button(self, label='Go')
        self.btn_go.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler=self.Start)
        hbox.Add(self.btn_go, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 12)

        self.SetSizer(hbox)

    def Start(self, event):
        my_frame.panel_step1.FillGrid(17, 8)
        my_frame.Layout()
        time.sleep(3)  # treatment simulation
        my_frame.panel_step2.Show()
        my_frame.panel_step2.FillGridPanel2()
        my_frame.Layout()


class PanelStep1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('green')
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox_title = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        title = wx.StaticText(self, label='Title panel 1')
        hbox_title.Add(title, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 6)
        self.sizer.Add(hbox_title, 0, wx.LEFT, 0)

        self.hbox_table = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.hbox_table, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.hbox_info = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.info = wx.StaticText(self, label='  number of lines : ')
        self.hbox_info.Add(self.info, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, 12)
        self.sizer.Add(self.hbox_info, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()

    def FillGrid(self, nb_lines, nb_columns):
        self.table = grid.Grid(self)
        self.hbox_table.Add(self.table, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, 18)
        self.table.CreateGrid(nb_lines, nb_columns)

        nb_lines += 1
        nb_columns += 1
        for l in range(1, nb_lines):
            for c in range(1, nb_columns):
                self.table.SetCellValue(l-1, c-1, 'data ' + str(l) + '-' + str(c))

        self.table.AutoSize()
        self.table.SetRowLabelSize(50)
        self.info.SetLabel('  number of lines : '+str(nb_lines))
        self.Layout()


class PanelStep2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('YELLOW')
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        title = wx.StaticText(self, label='Table panel 2')
        self.sizer.Add(title, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, 6)

        self.info = wx.StaticText(self, label='Information on data processing ...')
        self.info.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False))
        self.sizer.Add(self.info, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, 18)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def FillGridPanel2(self):
        nb_lines = 27
        nb_columns = 8
        self.table = grid.Grid(self)
        self.table.CreateGrid(nb_lines, nb_columns)
        for r in range(nb_lines):
            self.table.SetRowLabelValue(r, str(r+1)+'  ')
            self.table.SetRowLabelAlignment(wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.table.AutoSize()
        self.table.SetRowLabelSize(30)

        hbox_table = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox_table.Add(self.table, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 6)
        self.sizer.Add(hbox_table, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 12)

        self.Layout()


class MyApp(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        font = wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False)
        self.SetFont(font)

        self.panel_choice = PanelChoice(self)
        self.panel_step1 = PanelStep1(self)
        self.panel_step2 = PanelStep2(self)
        self.panel_step2.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_choice, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_step1, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_step2, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetupScrolling()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(0)
    screen_width, screen_height = wx.GetDisplaySize()
    win_width = min(screen_width, 1280)
    win_height = min(screen_height, 800)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, title='My application', size=(win_width, win_height))
    my_frame = MyApp(frame)
    frame.CreateStatusBar()
    frame.Show()
    frame.Center()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have understood your question correctly, but you have misunderstood the way that  python's *time* function works: as you have written it, the timer is started, but python continues to process the rest of the code in the function.

Better to use wx.Python's Timer (see this [tutorial](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/) from Mike Driscoll).

Therefore, in your *Start* function use:

```
def Start(self, event):
    my_frame.panel_step1.FillGrid(17, 8)
    my_frame.Layout()
    self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.timer.StartOnce(3000)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self._display_second_panel, self.timer)

def _display_second_panel(self, event):
    my_frame.panel_step2.Show()
    my_frame.panel_step2.FillGridPanel2()
    my_frame.Layout()
```

On a more general note, you have made the Frame a child of the panel

See the [wxPython Panel documentation](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Panel.html)

> A panel is a window on which controls are placed.
> It is usually placed within a frame. Its main feature over its parent class wx.Window is code for handling child windows and TAB traversal, which is implemented natively if possible (e.g. in wxGTK) or by wxWidgets itself otherwise.

and [Overview of wxPython](https://wxpython.org/pages/overview/)

You should define a frame first and have all of the panels as children of the frame

This is how it might look

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled
import wx.grid as grid


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        screen_width, screen_height = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        win_width = min(screen_width, 1280)
        win_height = min(screen_height, 800)
        self.Size = (win_width, win_height)
        self.Title = 'Wx App'
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)

        self.panel_choice = PanelChoice(self)
        self.panel_step1 = PanelStep1(self)
        self.panel_step2 = PanelStep2(self)
        self.panel_step2.Hide()

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel_choice, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.panel_step1, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.panel_step2, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)

        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('F00FF')
        font = wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False)
        self.SetFont(font)

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetupScrolling()


class PanelChoice(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PanelChoice, self).__init__(parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('BLUE')
        self.parent = parent

        h_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label='Select data')
        h_box.Add(self.label, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 12)

        list_choice = [str(choice) for choice in range(1, 7)]
        self.choice = wx.ComboBox(self, choices=list_choice)
        self.choice.SetValue('1')
        h_box.Add(self.choice, 0,  wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 3)

        self.btn_go = wx.Button(self, label='Go')
        self.btn_go.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler=self.Start)
        h_box.Add(self.btn_go, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 12)

        self.SetSizer(h_box)

    def Start(self, event):
        self.parent.panel_step1.FillGrid(17, 8)
        self.parent.Layout()
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.StartOnce(3000)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self._display_second_panel, self.timer)

    def _display_second_panel(self, event):
        self.parent.panel_step2.Show()
        self.parent.panel_step2.FillGridPanel2()
        self.parent.Layout()


class PanelStep1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('green')
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        h_box_title = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        title = wx.StaticText(self, label='Title panel 1')
        h_box_title.Add(title, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 6)
        self.sizer.Add(h_box_title, 0, wx.LEFT, 0)

        self.h_box_table = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.h_box_table, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.h_box_info = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.info = wx.StaticText(self, label='  number of lines : ')
        self.h_box_info.Add(self.info, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, 12)
        self.sizer.Add(self.h_box_info, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()

    def FillGrid(self, nb_lines, nb_columns):
        self.table = grid.Grid(self)
        self.h_box_table.Add(self.table, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, 18)
        self.table.CreateGrid(nb_lines, nb_columns)

        nb_lines += 1
        nb_columns += 1
        for line_number in range(1, nb_lines):
            for c in range(1, nb_columns):
                self.table.SetCellValue(line_number-1, c-1, 'data ' + str(line_number) + '-' + str(c))

        self.table.AutoSize()
        self.table.SetRowLabelSize(50)
        self.info.SetLabel('  number of lines : '+str(nb_lines))
        self.Layout()


class PanelStep2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('YELLOW')
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        title = wx.StaticText(self, label='Table panel 2')
        self.sizer.Add(title, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, 6)

        self.info = wx.StaticText(self, label='Information on data processing ...')
        self.info.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False))
        self.sizer.Add(self.info, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, 18)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def FillGridPanel2(self):
        nb_lines = 27
        nb_columns = 8
        self.table = grid.Grid(self)
        self.table.CreateGrid(nb_lines, nb_columns)
        for r in range(nb_lines):
            self.table.SetRowLabelValue(r, str(r+1)+'  ')
            self.table.SetRowLabelAlignment(wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.table.AutoSize()
        self.table.SetRowLabelSize(30)

        h_box_table = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        h_box_table.Add(self.table, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 6)
        self.sizer.Add(h_box_table, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 12)

        self.Layout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app = wx.App()
    MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In fact, between the display of panel 1 and panel 2, a data analysis method of several dozen lines is called. Its execution takes several seconds. To simplify the presentation I replaced it in my example with a timer.

To summarise: 1. display panel 1 (with the starting data) 2. process the data (processing method that is simulated in my example by the timer) 3. display the results in panel 2.
In further development there will be further processing followed by the display of a new panel and so on.

Comment: When the analysis finishes, call _display_second_panel()!

Comment: Scrollbar appear on grid 2 when panel 2 is shown and not on MainPanel

Comment: I get no scrollbar on my screen. You need to ask a separate question. You are posting redundant code here that is not relevant to the question. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (see this [code of a wxPython application](https://pastebin.com/pn86mFiK)). It is customary here to mark the question as answered if it is and to upmark the answer if it explains why it applies